# What does “congressional math” mean?

Tags: american-english

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of the phrase  “congressional math”? Is it some kind of political slang?

I’ve looked it up in all free dictionaries.

The source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6GDT-7o6DA 9:23

Comment: You might want to look up: Passing bills in Congress. A majority is needed. Math is just a way to say: the required number of votes needed to pass a bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Congressional math" is used as short-hand when talking about the likelihood of:

1. Something coming to a vote (could be blocked/delayed by the composition of the committees it has to go through, or could be blocked by the 60 vote super-majority required to end debate in the Senate for most bills)
2. Something passing once voted on

As an example, "The congressional math doesn't add up" would be a phrase indicating the bill is almost certain to fail (the number or position of those firmly opposed guarantee it will die).

Comment: It always bugs me when people say 'math' or 'maths' (British English) when what they are talking about is simple arithmetic.

Comment: The cited video said "congressional arithmetic."  And in context, ShadowRanger's answer seems to be correct, and I added a thumbs-up.  Just for breadth, you might want to include some mention of the idea of "horse trading" meaning some politicians might be willing to vote for it if they got something they wanted. So the arithmetic edges into the more grey areas of politics quite quickly. How much does a politician's integrity add up to? Or, I might be more cynical than you.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: American English does not make a strong distinction between the two; "arithmetic" is rarely used, and is considered a subset of "math" in general ("arithmetic" is treated as synonymous with "(simple) math"). The occasional pedant will try to make the distinction, but elementary school kids go to "math class", even when they're in first grade, you mostly refer to it as arithmetic in specific idioms (e.g. "the three Rs: reading, writing and 'rithmetic").

Comment: @Dan: "horse trading" seems at best tangential. You can "make the math add up" (read: successfully pass a bill that might otherwise have died) by doing it, but it's just one of a ton of different idioms used in the political sphere; adding it would just distract from the answer.